# MySQL stored procedures mature? A good way to go or not for my scenario

Tags: mysql

I'm porting a reporting application from .net / MSSQL to php / MySQL and could use some advice from the MySQL experts out there.
I haven't done anything with MySQL for a few years, and when I was last using it stored procedures were brand new and I was advised to stay away from them because of that newness.
So, now that it's 2011, I was wondering if there's anything inherently "bad" about using them, as they worked so well for this app in MSSQL. I know it will depend on the needs of my app, so here are the high level points: (This will run on Linux if that matters)

- The app generates a very complex report, however it is NOT a high concurrency app, typically 1-2 users at a time, 5 concurrent would shock me. I can even throttle it to prevent more than 2 or so users from using it simultaneously, so a lot of concurrent users is not going to be a concern.
- Virtually 100% of the heavy lifting in this app in in the MSSQL stored procedure. The data is uploaded via the web front end, the stored procedure then takes it from there, and eventually spits out a csv / excel file for the user a few minutes later.

This works great using an MSSSQL stored procedure. However it's a good 2000 lines of sql code and I'm hesitant to submit the sql statements one at a time via php as opposed to using a stored procedure. Most importantly, it works fine with the current architecture, I'm not looking to change it unless I have to in order to accommodate MySQL / PHP.

Any gotchas in using a MySql stored procedure? Are they buggier than submitting sql statements or anything odd like that?

Thanks in advance for everyone's thoughts on this.

Comment: Stored procedures in MySQL do work, but this question is very vague and would at best invoke a discussions on the marrit of various database platforms. Consider revising the question to be much more specific, or posting it on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or a similar site.

Comment: It's a big fat chunk of sql that works really well as a stored procedure in MSSQL and I'm wondering if there's any gotchas with stored procedures in MySQL in a low concurrency environment. Not sure how that's vague or would invoke any marrit discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures in MySQL are quite [verbose in syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html), and [are hard to debug or profile](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/06/12/mysql-stored-procedures-problems-and-use-practices/).  Personally I think they are very useful in some cases, but I would be very hesitant to try to maintain a 2000+ line stored procedure in MySQL.